# in android studio i am using AppCompat api28 , how can i change toolbar attributes like background color and etc in style.xml file?

Tags: android, android-theme

I have tried many options but whatever I use, it seems I cannot change the toolbar or action bar color & styles in the 'style.xml' file. it seems like using 'android.support.v7.widget.toolbar' is my only option . do you know a way so that I can change action bar styles in 'style.xml' file?

```
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

and in the manifest i used 'CustomActionBarTheme' as my default theme .

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: I have sent my code, although its nothing special, very routine work.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution , my first mistake was that i should use a theme like :
'Theme.AppCompat.Light' , anything that starts with Theme , and finally creating an style like bellow , with parent set to 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar'

```
    <style name="customActionbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@color/your_custom_color</item>
       // also notice you must use color.xml file for colors and for some attributes
       // like titleTextStyle , you must define another style and use it here like :
       <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/your_title_text_style</item>
    </style>

   <style name="your_title_text_style">
       <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_text_color</item>
   </style>
```

you can find all other properties of ActionBar bellow :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#ActionBar